# Ruby on Rails error:AssociationRelation is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following view:

```
# index.html.web
<h1>Listing answers</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

  <%= render [@answers]%>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

And the following `index` action:

```rb
def index
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @answers = @question.answers.paginate(page: params[:page])
  respond_with(@answers)
end
```

I'm getting the following errror:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Answer id: 2, content: "b", user_id: nil, question_id: 1, created_at: "2015-04-27 14:59:32", updated_at: "2015-04-27 14:59:32">, #<Answer id: 3, content: "d", user_id: 1, question_id: 1, created_at: "2015-04-27 15:15:01", updated_at: "2015-04-27 15:15:01"] is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a `collection of instances` to render the partial, you don't need to put any square bracket around the instance.

```
<%= render @answers %>
```

And don't forget to create a view name `_answer.html.erb` as well

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Comment: You need `render collection:` as `@answers` is not a single instance.

Comment: @fylooi Thank you very much.  I used the wrong wording. just edited.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in two different ways.

```
<%= render @answers %>  OR  
<%= render partial: 'answer', collection: @answers %>
```

In both cases, you will get an object named `answer` in partial view.

And you must have a file named `_answer.html.erb` should exists in same directory.

Answer (score 1):

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing answers</h1>

<%= will_paginate @answers%>

<%= render @answers%>

<%= will_paginate  @answers%>
```

There must be a partial called _answer.html.erb

The above mention line will call _answer.html.erb with answer object in a loop.